# How to make a valid string for XML in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, string, xml-entities

I'm looking for a function to convert a string to the xml string with xml entities where needed. Something like [htmlentities](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) in PHP but for XML and in Javascript.

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing built-in (except `innerHTML` serialisation which is super-dodgy for this purpose), you'd have to write it yourself, eg.:

```
function encodeXml(s) {
    return (s
        .replace(/&/g, '&amp;').replace(/"/g, '&quot;').replace(/'/g, '&apos;')
        .replace(/</g, '&lt;').replace(/>/g, '&gt;')
        .replace(/\t/g, '&#x9;').replace(/\n/g, '&#xA;').replace(/\r/g, '&#xD;')
    );
}
```

This is a maximalist escaping function for safety:

- it will always encode `"`, `'` and tab/CR/LF characters  though they only need to be escaped in an attribute value, where that particular quote character is being used as a delimiter.
- it will always encode `>` though this only actually needs to be escaped when part of the `]]>` sequence in text content.

If you don't need these properties you can remove the `replace`​s you don't need (it's pretty rare to need to put tab/CR/LF in an attribute value, for example).

If you need to produce HTML-compatible XHTML, use `&#39;` instead of `&apos;` if you need that escape.

In general you should avoid `htmlentities` and use `htmlspecialchars` instead, as `htmlentities` unnecessarily encodes all non-ASCII characters as HTML entity references, which also has the side-effect of screwing up your text if you don't give it the right `$charset` parameter.